# Spring boot doen't retrieve form data from SAML auth

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, rest

Well, I'm consuming SAML SSO created by enterprise where I work. Once user and password is typed SAML service redirects to given url as POST request, e.g.

```
https://some-saml-url.domine.com/idp/startSSO.ping
```

then fill up user and password fields and redirects to my app authentication url as POST with form data encrypted as `SAMLResponse`.
I'm using spring boot 2.4.5. Here my controller

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class AuthenticationController {

  @PostMapping(value = "/auth", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
  public String authentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws GasStationException {
    //do something to retrieve SAMLResponse
    return "redirect:/";
  }
}
```

I'm able to catch request inside controller but not to get form data. I've tried multiple solutions I've found through internet but nothing. Hope somebody have an idea or  solution that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if somebody have this kind of issue and is using logbook, well that's why. In logback file I have this one

```
<logger name="org.zalando.logbook" level="TRACE" />
```

And don't know why logbook takes form data values print them in console and delete them from request. After comment this line all works.